# Derivation of Abraham–Lorentz–Dirac force

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

According to Dirac, the equation of motion of classical point electrons is

\begin{equation}\label{key}
 \frac{d p_{\mu}}{d\tau} = F^{ext}_{\mu} + F^{rad}_{\mu}.
\end{equation}

How can it be derived the expression for the radiative reaction force $F^{rad}_{\mu}$ from this?

\begin{equation}
 F^{rad}_{\mu} = \frac{\mu_{0} e^2}{6 \pi m c}\left[ \frac{d^2 p_{\mu}}{d\tau^2} - \frac{p_{\mu}}{m^2 c^2} \left( \frac{d p_{\nu}}{d\tau} \frac{d p^{\nu}}{d\tau} \right) \right].
\end{equation}

And what would be necessary to show that it reduces to the Abraham–Lorentz force in the non-relativistic case?